# HTML5 Canvas API

Tags: html5-canvas

Below script is not drawing the complete image on canvas. Trying to draw 400 * 346 px image from the sprite.Tested with chrome, safari, mozilla

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">    
    var canvas = null;
    function init() {
        var cvs = document.createElement("canvas");
        cvs.id = "myCanvas";
        var ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
        var originX = 200;
        var originY = 173;
        document.body.appendChild(cvs);
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            var sourceX = 1200;
            var sourceY = 0;
            var sourceWidth = 400;
            var sourceHeight = 346;
            var destinationX = 0;
            var destinationY = 0;
            var destinationWidth = 400;
            var destinationHeight = 346;
            ctx.drawImage(img, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight,
                          destinationX, destinationY, destinationWidth, destinationHeight);
        };
        img.src = 'tiles.png';
    };

    init();
</script>
</body>
```

Kindly help.

Comment: What do you think where the error comes from? Do you see error messages in the console? Have you tried logging things to see if their output is what you expect it to be. Don't just throw a piece of code in here and tell other people to make it work.

Comment: i tried... code works fine. No error message. But it doesn't draw the complete image from the sprite. i am not able to upload image because of insufficient privileges 'not enough reputations'. Also each image in sprite is 400 * 346 px.

Comment: Fixed it ...

cvs.setAttribute('width', '1000');
cvs.setAttribute('height', '1000');
where cvs is the canvas object and not the context.

-MS

Answer (score 2):

You don't assign the canvas a width or height. So it defaults to 300x150, which is smaller than your image, hence only part of the image is displayed.

Try adding something like `cvs.width = 400; cvs.height = 346;`